# image sprites as background on webpage

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is there a way to optimize page loading times of a sprite/texture based background on a website?

Basically the look I'm trying to go for, is a 2d representation of Minecraft, with everything above the grassline to be a header, and bedrock as the footer.

Similar to [www.projectminecraft.com](http://www.planetminecraft.com) and [www.dokucraft.co.uk](http://www.dokucraft.co.uk)

But I'm worried about page load times, yet want to have caves and other details.

Comment: A sprite-sheet is an excellent thing to implement.

Are you asking if that's a good idea? Or how to use it?

Comment: Maybe you can try some like this ? http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: I'm pretty new to current css and html trends, last time I touched css css2 was new and hardly supported.

I'm asking for techniques and starting places to look to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a sprite-sheet, create one large png (or jpg if you'd like and there's no transparency) that has all of your images on it. ([example](http://media.smashingmagazine.com/images/css-sprites/amazon.png))

Next, for each element you want to have an image, set the background to something like:

`background:url(my-sprite-sheet.png) 10px 40px no-repeat;`

In this example, the coordinates relate to your sprite sheet. It tells the background to have the upper-left corner of the background begin at 10px from the right of your image and 40px from the bottom. (strangely enough, 0 0 would be the upper-left corner of your image)

As far as I know, you can't do this for repeated (tiled) backgrounds. For that, have each "tile" as it's own image and use something like `background:url(my-background.png);`. By default, the image will repeat on both the x and y axis. You can further define the repeat with `repeat-x` `repeat-y` and `no-repeat`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For a large background of repeated content you'd want to create an image that tiles in it's smallest form, then use `background-repeat: repeat` in your CSS.

If it's not possible to tile the entire thing, then try and tile as much as possible (the edges and bottom are usually a good place). Don't forget you can use multiple background images in modern browsers ([see their adoption in browsers on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds)).

The second example you listed does however uses [one large `png`](http://dokucraft.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Website-Wallpaper.png), and in this case, you should ensure you're only using the minimum colours you require and compress the image as far as you can with something like http://imageoptim.com/.